# In python Is there a way to test if an object is in an enumerable, but in the sense of the "is" operator instead of the "==" operator?

Tags: python, operators, identity

I'm displaying a data structure which is supposed to be a tree, but there might be some risks of infinite recursion if my tree if in reality a graph with cycles (That shouldn't happen, but I'm playing paranoid).

For this reason, I have created list of encountered nodes and I want to check if the current visited node is present in the list. However, it appears that the `in` operator is testing on values (like `==`) and not on identity (like `is`). Would there be a way to check if an object "identity" instead of "value" is already present in my list ?

Comment: Do you have access to the node object?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the value in your list, put the identity which you can get with the `id(object)` function which returns it's address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom class inheriting from `list` that changes the `__contains__` method to compare based on `a is b` instead of `a == b`

```
class IdList(list):
    def __contains__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return any(__o is s for s in self)

# Here's how it works
o1 = str(123)
o2 = str(456)
o3 = str(789)

l1 = IdList([o1, o2, o3])
l2 = list([o1, o2, o3])

o1_2 = str(123)

print(f"{o1 in l1 = }") # True
print(f"{o1 in l2 = }") # True
print(f"{o1_2 in l1 = }") # False
print(f"{o1_2 in l2 = }") # True
```

Comment: That much more complicated than my solution, but it is much nearer from what I was originally looking for. Good point, thank you.